# How to change the distance between columns in a two column footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, ledmac

I'm using `eledmac`'s `\foottwocolX` to put my footnotes into two columns, but can't find a way to reduce the white space between those two columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\TeXXeTstate=1

\usepackage{eledmac}

\foottwocolX{A}

\begin{document}
hello%

\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello }  
\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello }  
\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello }  
\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello }  
\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello }  
\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello }  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [documentation of `eledmac`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eledmac/eledmac.pdf), it's explained in "4.3.6 Options for notes in columns".

`\hsizetwocol[<s>]{<l>}` is used to change width of a column when critical notes are displaying in two columns. Default value is `.45\hsize`. `<s>` means the series.

Be careful that the columns are made from right to left.

Comment: I missed it since I only looked at the "footnotes" section. Worked like a charm, great work by the way ! ; "be careful that the columns are made from right to left." : That's one of my problems for my Hebrew document, I'll look for a way to switch to right-to-left columns.

Comment: Oh, please open a ticket in the github, with a minimal example. I will try to correct it.